# in WCF service can callback be made using wsHttpbinding?

Tags: wcf, windows-services

I am new to WCF and windows services.
I have wcf service that is called from a class library. I am using that library in Windows service(WS) and this WS subscribes to the services and executes call back methods. The problem here is when I use
wsDualHttpBinding, I get an exception at the highlighted line

```
                subscribe () {
                InstanceContext ctx = new InstanceContext(this);
                fcsc = new FeatureCreationServiceClient(ctx, "MyEndPoint"); //error
                fcsc.Subscribe();
```

error says

> Could not find endpoint element with name 'xx' and contract 'xx' in the ServiceModel client configuration section.

Some of our friends in StackOverFlow suggested  replacing wsDualHttpBinding with WShttpBinding. Now the problem is gone but there is new exception saying

> Contract requires Duplex, but Binding 'WSHttpBinding' doesn't support it or isn't configured properly to support it.

Please help me.  I know that some one might have already asked this question but my search for that was in vain. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: `wsHttpBinding` is not duplex.  Try `wsDualHttpBinding` instead - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731821%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Hi Tim, I replaced wsHttpBinding with wsDualHttpBinding to overcome the first error mentioned in the question.